# Get orders id in DESC using magento soap api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, soap-api-v1

```
$session = $client->login('Sandbox', 'ek7PswHDZtHDWtY0O3xLcyUYFIBUtFMW');

$orders = $client->call($session, 'order.list');
```

This gets the order in ASC order by default. I want to get orders in DESC orders and also want to add a limit.